# Wordpress .php file changes not reflected not even after server restart

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, iis

I'm running a Wordpress site and I changed a .php file which creates the email for a contact form.
I'm running this with IIS on Windows 2012 R2 with PHP 5.6 as FastCGI module.

What I already tried.
- Clear the client/browser cache (but as far as I know php is serverside)
- Disable IIS Output caching completly
- Disable IIS Output caching for .php file
- Restarted the server
- Restarted the website in IIS Manager
- Renamed the file locally
- Reuploaded the file via FTP
- Disabled wincache extension in php.ini
- Cleared Windows temp dir
- Cleared IIS temp dir
- Checked the dir which serves the content (that I don't change a possible duplicate)

I changed the header and message of the generated email, and when I send a mail using the contact form I also received the messages with the correct content but not with the updated header and message-formatting.

Currently I don't have any idea what else I should try or how to solve the problem. I mean currently it's only one file, but what if I have to do a wordpress update.
Somehow it is cached or a preloaded state is saved somewhere but I don't know where.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a kind of black box approach: download eXtplorer or another PHP based file manager, run it with any browser and change the PHP file that way (replace the PHP file via another PHP script.) If PHP works, this usually would work too. It does not constitute a permanent solution, but may be a kind of temporary one.